# ListView not drawing every listitem

Tags: android, listview

I am having a problem and I really can't find what's causing it.

I have a ListView that has 4 item types (getViewTypeCount() returns 4). View types 0, 1, and 3  are working perfectly. However, the problem with View type 2 is that only some of the items with type 2 are drawn. The View that represents type 2 is a ViewPager.

The ViewPagers that are drawn work perfectly. The ViewPagers that are not drawn, just show white. When I try to scroll through that ViewPager, it shows the blue glow at the side to show that you are on the first or last page. The amount of pages is correct every time.

The ViewPager contain one NormalSectionFragment and the rest of the ViewPager are pages with a photo on each page PhotoSectionFragments.

There are a few things I am sure of:

- The onCreateView method of the Fragments in the ViewPager is called every time the ViewPager appears (or should appear)
- When I scroll all the way down and back up, every ViewPager is drawn and working perfectly

I could solve it by programmatically scrolling down and back up, but I don't think this is the correct way to solve it.

[image: Screenshot with item view types]

getItemViewType method:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    NieuwsItem item = getItem(position);
    if (item instanceof NormalNieuwsItem)
        return VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL;
    else
        if (item instanceof TeaserNieuwsItem)
            return VIEW_TYPE_TEASER;
        else
            return ((FacebookNieuwsItem) item).isPhoto() ? VIEW_TYPE_FACEBOOK_PHOTO : VIEW_TYPE_FACEBOOK;
}
```

Here is the getView() method of the list adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    NieuwsItem item = getItem(position);

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
    case 0:
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_nieuwsitem, null);

        TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
        TextView subTitleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subTitleView);
        titleView.setText(item.getTitle());
        subTitleView.setText(item.getSubTitle());
        TextView createdAtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.createdAtView);
        createdAtView.setText(Tools.getDateString(getContext(), ((NormalNieuwsItem) item).getCreatedAt()));

        return convertView;
    case 1:
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_teaseritem, null);

        TextView teaserTitleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.teaserTitle);
        ImageView teaserImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.teaserImage);
        teaserTitleView.setText(item.getTitle());
        Bitmap bmp = ((TeaserNieuwsItem) item).getImage();
        if (bmp != null)
            teaserImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        return convertView;
    case 2:
        FacebookNieuwsItem fbPhotoItem = (FacebookNieuwsItem) item;

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_facebookitem_photo, null);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.facebookPhotoPager);
        PhotoPagerAdapter adapter = new PhotoPagerAdapter(fm, fbPhotoItem);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setPageMargin(-40);
        pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);

        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        return convertView;
    case 3:
        FacebookNieuwsItem fbItem = (FacebookNieuwsItem) item;

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_facebookitem, null);
        TextView content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_content);
        TextView likeCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_likecount);
        TextView commentCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_commentcount);
        TextView createdAt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_date);

        if (fbItem.isPhoto())
            content.setText(fbItem.getTitle());
        else
            content.setText(fbItem.getContent());
        likeCount.setText(Integer.toString(fbItem.getLikeCount()));
        commentCount.setText(Integer.toString(fbItem.getCommentCount()));
        createdAt.setText(Tools.getDateString(getContext(), fbItem.getCreatedAt()));

        return convertView;
    default:
        return null;
    }

}
```

Adapter for the ViewPager:

```
public class PhotoPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private FacebookNieuwsItem item;

    public PhotoPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, FacebookNieuwsItem item) {
        super(fm);
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment;
        if (i == 0)
            fragment = NormalSectionFragment.newInstance(item);
        else {
            String url = Tools.PHOTO_URL_PREFIX + item.getPhoto(i - 1) + Tools.PHOTO_URL_SUFFIX;
            fragment = PhotoSectionFragment.newInstance(url);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Integer.toString(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.getPhotoCount() + 1;
    }

}
```

PhotoSectionFragment:

```
public static class PhotoSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageView image;
    private String url;

    public static PhotoSectionFragment newInstance(String url) {
        PhotoSectionFragment fragment = new PhotoSectionFragment();
        fragment.setUrl(url);
        return fragment;
    }

    private void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public PhotoSectionFragment() {
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 100, 60, true);
        bmp.recycle();
        image.setImageBitmap(scaled);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("photo_oncreateview_start", "url: " + url);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fb_photo_item, null);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.facebookPhoto);

        return view;
    }
}
```

NormalSectionFragment:

```
public static class NormalSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    private FacebookNieuwsItem item;

    public NormalSectionFragment() {
    }

    public static NormalSectionFragment newInstance(FacebookNieuwsItem item) {
        NormalSectionFragment section = new NormalSectionFragment();
        section.setItem(item);
        return section;
    }

    private void setItem(FacebookNieuwsItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("reg_oncreateview_start", item.getTitle());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_facebookitem_viewpager, null);
        TextView content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_content);
        TextView likeCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_likecount);
        TextView commentCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_commentcount);
        TextView createdAt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_date);

        content.setText(item.getTitle());
        likeCount.setText(Integer.toString(item.getLikeCount()));
        commentCount.setText(Integer.toString(item.getCommentCount()));
        createdAt.setText(DateTimeUtils.getInstance(getActivity()).getTimeDiffString(item.getCreatedAt().getTimeInMillis()));

        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).requestNieuwsDetailPage(item);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: For debug. Have you try to return convertView instead of null in your default case in your getView to check if there is a problem there.

Comment: Even thought you say it is implemented correctly, can you show your getItemViewType

Comment: I tried that, but still same result. Also, added getItemViewType in question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using normal Views instead of Fragments. Didn't know it was possible